# Is it a problem for wrong gender on flight tickets?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airasia

I just booked a flight ticket on [AirAsia](http://www.airasia.com/) for my friend and filled out the wrong gender carelessly. Is it a problem?

I didn't find their customer service phone numbers on [AirAsia](http://www.airasia.com/).

Comment: You can contact AirAsia through their [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/AirAsia/?fref=ts) and ask them for help with it. They are very responsive

Comment: When flying Heathrow-Helsinki the airline decided my Mum "Jean" must be a man. Nobody batted an eyelid. They probably didn't even check it.

Comment: @RedSonja It doesn't mean your mum wouldn't have any problems if they did check.

Comment: I know that the comments about trans/gender identity are jokes, but in all seriousness if you did this it would likely cause *more* problems for you. It does somewhat depend on where you are traveling.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### You can change it for free

According to [this tweet exchange](https://twitter.com/airasia/status/229805090821795840) the airline has no problem changing the title on tickets (March 2016).

Comment: Thx. I made it.

Answer (score 7):

I just flew with Gulf Air and my ticket/boarding pass was labelled Mr when I'm clearly a female. The default gender was Mr on the website when I purchased the ticket, and there was no attention drawn to gender choice at that time. I emailed them and was told it would cost US$25 to change the gender and the Gulf Air person indicated that I should do so. As this was about 10% of the flight cost, I decided to wait and do it at the airport if there was a problem. Thankfully, no-one commented on it at any time.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not a problem, and you don't have to change it. I've flown on European flights a couple of times with the wrong gender selected for my travel partner and not one airline bat an eye. If you search on Flyertalk you will find [other reports](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/finnair-finnair-plus/1442095-wrong-gender-reservation-2.html) confirming the same. Likewise airlines [don't care if your passport number or date of birth is invalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da) when entered during online check-in.

Just make sure the name is correct and you're good to go.

Comment: May I ask why so often your partner's gener was wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I faced gender problem at the time of web checkin at AirAsia flight, it was showing male, after talking to customer care this was solved. They said it's system error could be fixed online & gender was updated correct. Hope some of u got their solution.